# Generate a sunburst plot from a list of strings

Tags: data-visualization, language

I am looking for a program that can generate a [sunburst plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pie_chart&oldid=882120375#Ring_chart,_sunburst_chart,_and_multilevel_pie_chart) from a list of strings.

For example, if I have a list of strings:

```
How many glasses are on the tab ?
What does the sign say ?
Has the pizza been baked ?
Do you think the boy on the ground has broken legs ?
Is this man crying ?
How many pickles are on the plate ?
What is the shape of the plate?
…
```

The sunburst plot shows the distribution of questions by their first four words, the arc length is proportional to the number of questions containing the word and the white areas are words with contributions too small to show.

[image]

([Image source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00468v7.pdf) -> page 5, figure 3)

Any license, operating system and price is fine. The plot shouldn't rely on dynamic elements to be understood (e.g., one shouldn't have to mouse over somewhere to see the word corresponding to a node).

https://github.com/codebox/wordvis only allows for one letter in each node. (feature request to allow nodes to represent words and not just letters: https://github.com/codebox/wordvis/issues/3)

Even better if the sunburst plot is [interactive](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#basic-sunburst-plot-with-plotlyexpress):

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's good that you found that `wordvis` project on GitHub (and linked to it here). It shouldn't be particularly difficult for someone fluent in Python to adapt it to your use case.

Comment: @JohnY Probably. Since sunbursts are quite popular I'm assuming that the piece of software somewhere that one can use directly without amending the code.

Comment: Frank, do you care about programming language / framework?   Normally, I would go to D3JS for this, if using any form of JS. e.g [here's an example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst) Looks like it also [works with Python[(https://www.fullstackpython.com/d3-js.html)